# How do I switch between powerups?

Tags: tetris-axis

When playing Tetris Axis with Items turned on, is there a way to switch between powerups? If I have an item that switches my screen with my opponent's, and an item that adds blocks to their screen, and I am doing well, I won't want to switch screens with them, but I might want to add blocks to their screen, for example.

The default is for your powerups to line up, and when you press X you use the powerup in the first slot. Is there a way to cycle between slots, so I can have my pick of items?

Comment: I think you're meant to strategize which powerup to use and when to use them. Otherwise it seems a bit unfair... especially with the screen swapping powerup.

Comment: @Krazer Oh, probably, but it is rather annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

Unofortunately, No, you can't.